# Detecting a file read in Java

Tags: java, database, eclipse, windows, multithreading

It is easy to detect file write or modification but I cannot think of a way to detect a file read. Here is the scenario.

Program X (which I have no control of) READS Sample.text and MODIFIES it. It should be noted that Program X closes the stream immediately after the READ.

I am to write a program to record the duration/time from the READ to the MODIFICATION of Sample.txt. For example, Program X read Sample.txt at 5:00 PM and modifies it at 7:25 PM so the total duration is 2 hrs and 25 min.

Is there a package or a workaround to detect when/if Sample.txt was read by Program X? Please note READ is what I want to detect as supposed to MODIFIED as java.nio.file can detect a file modification.

Comment: I would be rather surprised ... if that is possible at all; and beyond that, if the jvm would be able to provide such a solution that would really work on platforms that java runs on.

Comment: Is this for production environment or for debug ? Your use case let me think you are trying to wonder why the X program is taking so long between read and modification. If I'm right, what you need is a profiler, and not a java API like WatchService (which does indeed NOT contains anything to watch the reads).

Comment: you can write your own IO interceptor on OS level, just like antivirus and call it with JNI. Not easy, but possible. But i really think you don't need such thing.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like reading one of the [BasicFileAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html), the `lastAccessTime`, is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help -

1. Track the file read time in the Program X.
2. Always store the read time in the DB.
3. Once the file gets modified find the difference between the recorded read time and modified time.